# How to detect current orientation of a view controller iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

In my application manually sets the orientation according to view controller. Besides this view controllers, I need to detect current orientation of the most top view controller(**Not the Device orientation**). Is it possible?

This is how I set the orientation.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: **ViewController** orientation automatically changed with **Device orientation** so the device orientation is your **ViewController orientation**.

Comment: No.  I Manually sets the orientation of a view controller.

Comment: could you share your code about setting orientation of view controllers ?

Comment: @ArashEtemad updated

Answer (score 0):

As said, you want to check the current orientation set in your root/ top most  VC.

So you can detect with this code:-

```
if (topViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) else{
        // view is set to portrait 
        return .portrait;
    }
    // // view is set to landscape 
    return .allButUpsideDown;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set orientation of each view controller by:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    var _orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get { return self._orientations }
    set { self._orientations = newValue }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //...
}
```

and then read this property everywhere you want like:

```
let vc = YourViewController()
print(vc._orientation)
```